# Automatic scrolling on load to show all of a page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/z3YvT/ - with an absolutely positioned orange box:

```
div#box2 {
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:orange;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
    right:400px;
}
```

Currently the box is offset 50px above the top of the page, so we only see the bottom 100px of the 150px box.  I would like the page to load so that it automatically scrolls to show all of the box.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can also investigate the javascript scrollBy function.  It only works if your scroll-bar is present, and I couldn't get it to scroll up, only down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3YvT/1/)

---

You can't really scroll the page, but you can scroll the objects in the page; or perhaps you want to scroll the `body`:

```
$('body').css('position','relative').animate({top:'50px'})
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3YvT/6/)

---

Using your new criteria, you probably want to scan the offsets of all elements and adjust accordingly:

```
var min = { top: 0, $el: {} };

// Scan all Elements
$('body *').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        _top = $this.offset().top;

    if (_top < min.top) {
        min.top = _top;
        min.$el = $this;
    }
});

// Adjust Accordingly
$('body').css('position', 'relative').animate({
    top: (min.top * -1) + 'px'
})
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/z3YvT/11/)

Comment: Ok, that look promising. One more detail.  I won't know that the right amount to move is 50px.  Someone could have put an element anywhere.  I need to sense the highest thing on the page and scroll to get it in  the view port.